# poetry install multiple projects in the same environment

Tags: python-poetry, pyproject.toml

I'm trying to solve what I assume is a common problem with poetry but am unable to find the relevant documentation. My project includes multiple packages and uses pyproject.toml and poetry to manage dependencies with this structure

```
/pyproject.toml
/poetry.lock

/package1/pyproject.toml
/package1/poetry.lock
/package1/src/package1/...
```

`/package1/pyproject.toml` includes pypi dependencies in `[tool.poetry.dependencies]` and defines the buildable package as

```
packages = [
    { include = "package1", from = "./src" },
]
```

`/pyproject.toml` references `package1` with

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
package1 = { path = "./package1", develop = true }
```

Finally, my Dockerfile installs the application with

```
WORKDIR /app/package1
RUN poetry install
WORKDIR /app
RUN poetry install
```

The problem is that Poetry installs each "project" (identified by the pyproject.toml file) in a separate virtual environment, and doesn't seem to support installing both in the same environment. When I execute the application it can find `package1` but none of `package1`'s dependencies.

How can I get everything installed in the same environment?

How am I supposed to handle this situation?

Answer (score -4):

you will need to package each project. Using `poetry build`. This will give you a `.whl` file that you could submit to a package repository like PyPi or Gitlab Package Repository, e.g. using the python package `twine`. You will need to mention the source for the packages in your pyproject.toml if it is not PyPi. How to tell poetry to grab the .whl packages from a local source I do not know. But eventuall you have one poetry project and then install all other projects as packages (using the .whl files you have created).